# Python raw socket receive issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, raw-sockets

I am using the following python script for raw socket packet transfer. Packet transfer is fine, but I am not able to print the incoming packet from the other end.

```
from socket import socket, AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW

s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)
s.bind(("eth0", 0))
src_addr = "\x54\xbe\xf7\x40\xf5\x82"
dst_addr = "\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff"

payload = ("[("*30)+"Hello"+("]"*30)
checksum = "\x1a\x2b\x3c\x4d"

data = payload+checksum

s.send(dst_addr+src_addr+data)

#for receive function 

response=s.recv(4096)
print response
s.close()
```

Comment: Does the receiving end give any errors? What is the output of the print statement?

Comment: the server that receiving msgs should be always active, but seems that you closed the socket.

Comment: No I am get any print from "print response" Brandon. Its keep on waiting recv fn. Even after it receives from  client.

Comment: I tried without closing socket also but it is not capturing the incoming packets

Answer (score 6):

There is a third argument to the `socket` function: `protocol`. If not given, it's defaulting to 0. For `AF_PACKET / SOCK_RAW`, the `protocol` argument specifies what kind of packets you're interested in receiving. The values are documented in the `packet(7)` man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html

I don't think the values are actually defined anywhere in the core python2 modules. Some of them can be found in scapy (http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/), or you can just hunt up the linux header file where they are defined (`/usr/include/linux/if_ether.h`).

So, to fix this, change your code to:

```
from socket import socket, AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons

ETH_P_ALL = 3
ETH_P_IP = 0x800   # Alternatively using this will receive the next IP packet
s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))
...
```

Other comments on your code:

As written, the packet you're sending is unlikely to be comprehensible by anyone. You've got a dst and src MAC address, but then you're not providing an EtherType. Instead the first "[(" will be seen as the EtherType. That probably won't make sense to any receiver of the packet so it will just be discarded.

Also, you should understand that with a raw socket, you're going to receive the next packet of the type you've specified in the protocol. That isn't necessarily (and in fact probably won't be) a response to the packet you just sent.

Comment: I checked the linux man pages link, no protocol declarations there...Hunting them down in the if_ether.h file did the job...gr8!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone now I am able receive the packet with the following the script. But still I am facing issue with printing multiple response packets(While doing in loop).

```
from socket import socket, AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons
from struct import *
import select
import time

ETH_P_ALL = 3
ETH_P_IP = 0x800  
s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL))
s.bind(("eth0", 0))

src_addr = "\x54\xbe\xf7\x40\xf7\x82"
dst_addr = "\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff"   
l = "\x00\x21"

ethertype = "\x08\x01"

a ="\x00\x10\x00\x10\x00\x10"
b = "\x00\x11\x00\x11\x00\x11"

payload = ethertype + l + a + b

for i in range(5):

    time.sleep(5)   
    s.send(dst_addr+src_addr+ payload)
    message=s.recv(4096)
    print message
```

Comment: Could you please give better variable names, such as what is a and what is b